# How can I run a mysql query in ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

How can I run a `mysql` query in `ajax`?

So, I have a an `html` page. I load a grid with `ajax` and I should load other values, too. I try to tell what should I do:

`1` i got the data

`2` write it into the grid when user hits enter (myFunction(e) do this)

getfn(str) should do this:

`3`shearch in the mysql database

`4` write into the grid.

[image: Workflow]

**The Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
error_reporting ( E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

?>
<html>
  <head>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script type="text/javascript" >
      var dbs=0;
      var val=[];
      function myFunction(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 13){
          var newId = (new Date()).valueOf();
          var value=gridbox.cells(1,0).getValue();
          gridbox.addRow(newId,value);              
          val.push(value);
          gridbox.cells(1,0).setValue('');
          gridbox.editCell(1,0);
          dbs=dbs+1;
          getfn(value.substring(5,(value.indexOf(".")-4)));
          //val[0]=dbs;
        }
      }
      function upload(){
        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(val);

        var jsonData = $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "upload.php",
          data: { 'data' : jsonString},
          dataType:"json", 
          async: false
        }).responseText;


      }
      function getfn(str){
        //This should be the function
      }

    </script>


    <form  onkeydown="myFunction(event)" method="get">

      <?php


$xml = 'connector.php';
echo '

<div id="gridbox"   ></div>
<script>
doOnLoad("gridbox","'.$xml.'","0")
{   gridbox.enableAutoHeight(true);
gridbox.enableAutoWidth(true);

};
</script>
';
?>


    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. What is your question?

Comment: All `header()`-calls must be before any output... move that line to the top of the file.

Comment: Btw... why do you print the contents of you form using PHP? You have no PHP-specific code in there...

Comment: You are right man! I edit the descrptn

Comment: You're calling an undefined javascript function `doOnLoad()` and it looks like you have some serious syntax errors there as well...

Comment: Its working, i have a lots of callad script ( and one of this contains the doOnLoad() method)

Comment: The main point is that i have the 'value' and i should run a mysql with it in the getfn(value)